# Anonymous user persists in database after successful log in

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

Using Parse.com and anonymous users enabled (w/ automatic creation) - this is the scenario:

1. Start the app - anonymous user #1 gets created on database
2. Sign up with username & password - anonymous user #1 gets converted to regular user
3. Delete app - reinstall & start up - anonymous user #2 gets created
4. This time do not sign up but rather log in - log in successful, but anonymous user #2 persists in cloud.

How do I make anonymous user #2 from step 4 to go away (completely, I don't want junk in the database)?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: @LyndseyScott objective c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the user is otherwise logged out and you therefore know that `currentUser` either contains nil or the anonymous user object, you should be able to store the anonymous user object then delete that user object upon successful login, ex:

```
PFUser *anonymousUser;
if ([PFUser currentUser] != nil) {
    anonymousUser = [PFUser currentUser];
}

[PFUser logInWithUsernameInBackground:emailString password:passwordString block:^(PFUser* user, NSError* error){
    if (user) {
        if (anonymousUser)
            [anonymousUser deleteInBackground];
    }
}
```